# Telerik Appbuilder Cli build callback

Tags: javascript, batch-file, telerik, command-line-interface, telerik-appbuilder

I'm using Telerik AppBuilder Cli to build an app for IOS.  I am also using [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) which allows me to install the app directly onto my iPhone for debugging.

I'm using a batch script to build the app, and I want the same build script to install the app after the build is completed and the `.IPA` file is created.

The problem I am running into, is that there doesn't seem to be a proper callback when the Appbuilder Cli has finished building the app.  My attempted solution was to use the `&&` syntax like so:

```
appbuilder build `arguments` && goto install

:install

idevice install `arguments`
```

The form of my script has `:install` before the build ( so it can be used conditionally in case I want to build without installing ).   However the  `install callback` never fires.  I double-checked my conditional, and the only thing I can figure is that the Appbuilder Cli is ignoring the `&&` or something.

Is there a proper way to be notified when the build process is complete?  Or is there a javascript library for Appbuilder apart from the cli version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AppBuilder CLI has a command that will build and deploy the application directly. Just use:

```
appbuilder deploy <platform>
```

And this will deploy the application on the specified platform, for example ios.

You can find more information in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/running-on-devices/running-on-connected-devices/deploy-connected).

Also you can use `appbuilder help deploy` to check the help of the command.